# how does frame of a UILabel gets changed on changing anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView object with frame `(50, 50, 100, 100)`.
on this view object, I am adding a label with frame `(50, 50, 50, 10)`
Then I am changing the anchor point `from default` `(0.5, 0.5) to (1.0, 0.5)`
But surprisingly, the frame gets changed after that. Below is the code snippet for the same

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width/2, 10)];
NSLog(@"Label frame for %d label before anchor point shift is %@", i, NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));

label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
NSLog(@"Label frame for %d label after anchor point shift is %@", i, NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
```

Gives output :
Label frame for 0 label before anchor point shift is {{50, 50}, {50, 10}}
Label frame for 0 label after anchor point shift is {{25, 50}, {50, 10}}

Comment: I don't understand which is your question/problem

Comment: @Matteo My question was how frame of a UILabel is getting shifted when I am changing the anchor point of associated layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frame` of a `UIView` is a *derived* quantity based on the `center` and `bounds` properties.  If you change the `center` or `bounds`, then the `frame` is adjusted accordingly. Likewise, changing the `frame` adjusts the `center` and/or `bounds` as necessary.

Ok, that's great, except that you're changing the `anchorPoint` of the layer. When you change the `anchorPoint` of the layer, that changes the center point of the layer, which changes the center point of the UIView, which then changes the frame. Hence, the label moves.

Comment: More detailed explanation added as a separate answer below

Answer (score 2):

A CALayer has four properties that determine where it appears in its superlayer:
position (which is the same as the view's center property)
bounds (actually only the size part of bounds)
anchorPoint
transform
You will notice that frame is not one of those properties. The frame property is actually derived from those properties. When you set the frame property, the layer actually changes its center and bounds.size based on the frame you provide and the layer's existing anchorPoint.

You create the first layer (by creating the first UILabel, which is a subclass of UIView, and every UIView has a layer), giving it a frame of 50,50,50,10. The layer has a default anchor point of 0.5,0.5. So it computes its bounds as 0,0,50,10 and its position as 75,55.

By default anchorPoint and position are coinciding.
If we change anchorPoint to 1,0.5 it will change the position and hence center also to be at 100,55 . But instead of moving center/position it moves the frame of label. so if we want 75,55 as the new anchorPoint at 1,1, we will have to shift the frame  by -25,0 (75,55 - 100,55). hence frame gets changed from what is given by the console output.
Label frame for 0 label before anchor point shift is {{50, 50}, {50, 10}}
Label frame for 0 label after anchor point shift is {{25, 50}, {50, 10}}

Comment: This is a good explanation. I left out some of the details on purpose to avoid confusion. For example, a full discussion on the relationships between the `transform` and the `frame` gets messy.

Comment: "The layer has a default anchor point of 0.5,0.5. So it computes its bounds as 0,0,50,10 and its position as 75,55." I don't understand this part at all. How is the bounds 0,0,50,10 when the frame is 50,50,50,10?